# Unhandled Exception

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, knn

I am trying to implement a KNN algorithm out of interest via help code from a forum. The code is a follows.

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\ml.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cxcore.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int readFlippedInteger(FILE *);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("D:\\KNN\\train-images.idx3-ubyte", "rb");
        FILE *fp2 = fopen("D:\\KNN\\train-labels.idx1-ubyte", "rb");

    if(!fp || !fp2)
    {
        cout<<"Files not Found"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int magicNumber = readFlippedInteger(fp);
    int numImages = readFlippedInteger(fp);
    int numRows = readFlippedInteger(fp);
    int numCols = readFlippedInteger(fp);

    fseek(fp2, 0x08, SEEK_SET);

    int size = numRows*numCols;
    CvMat *trainingVectors = cvCreateMat(numImages, size, CV_32FC1);
    CvMat *trainingLabels = cvCreateMat(numImages, 1, CV_32FC1);

    //BYTE *temp = new BYTE[size];
    unsigned char *temp =  (unsigned char *) malloc(size);

    unsigned char tempClass=0;

    for(int i=0; i < numImages; i++)
    {
        fread((void*)temp, size, 1, fp);
        fread((void*)(tempClass), sizeof(unsigned char*), 1, fp2);

        trainingLabels->data.fl[i] = tempClass;

        for(int k=0; k < size; k++)
            trainingVectors->data.fl[i*size+k] = temp[k];
    }

    KNearest knn(trainingVectors, trainingLabels);
    printf("Maximum k: %d\n", knn.get_max_k());  

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);

    cvReleaseMat(&trainingVectors);
    cvReleaseMat(&trainingLabels);

    return 0;
}

int readFlippedInteger(FILE *fp)
{
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned char *temp;

    temp = (unsigned char*)(ret);
    fread(&temp[3], sizeof(unsigned char*), 1, fp);
    fread(&temp[2], sizeof(unsigned char*), 1, fp);
    fread(&temp[1], sizeof(unsigned char*), 1, fp);
    fread(&temp[0], sizeof(unsigned char*), 1, fp);

    return ret;
}
```

Instead of BYTE, I used unsigned char which I think should do the same work. Correct me if I am wrong here.

Nonetheless, I am not expert in programming but when I run the code i get this error

> *Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE68F7450 (msvcr110d.dll) in K-Nearest Neighbour.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0x0000000000000003

Can someone help me build this code.. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you miss the 'address-of' operator, and the sizeof seems wrong:

```
int readFlippedInteger(FILE *fp)
{
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned char *temp = (unsigned char*)(&ret);
    fread(&temp[3], sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fp);
    fread(&temp[2], 1, 1, fp);  // should be equivalent to above
    ...    
}
```

another problem could be the assumption that `int` is 4 bytes, because you're compiling using 64 bits, as is apparent from the error message.

Comment: Thank you.. It give debug assertation failed at runtime.

Comment: I think so because the error reads the path from fread.c  at line 147.Expresson (buffer!=NULL)

Comment: the culprit should be `fread((void*)(tempClass), sizeof(unsigned char*), 1, fp2);`.

Comment: i changed sizeof(unsigned char*) by removing the pointer and compiling in release mode and i got this error now 

Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in K-Nearest Neighbour.exe.

I think something is causing trouble in allocating the memory using fread. But i have no idea on solving it

Comment: Why switched to release mode? keep the debugger working! Of course, you should pay **much** attention to each 'raw' memory interfacing...

Comment: Hello! Infact you are absolutely correct its the fread((void*)(tempClass), sizeof(unsigned char*), 1, fp2); that is creating the problem.

Comment: I manage to solve it.. I replaced the above function with – fread(&tempClass, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fp2); and it worked. Trial and error method but it worked. Thanks for your help